# Removing a particular header item in HTTP web requests

Tags: c#, http-headers

I am currently using this method to retrieve headers from a particular site:

```
List<string> headers = new List<string>();
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    // headers.Add("URL: " + url);
    headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int)webResponse.StatusCode);
    headers.Add("Status Desc: " + webResponse.StatusDescription);
    headers.Add("Headers: " + webResponse.Headers);
}
```

With that said, it appears that when I try to request the headers from a `https` site, under the `header` section, it also displays the `Location`, which is the URL to our site. I would like to remove the `Location` from the `Headers` section of the C# code.

[image]

I would like the printed headers to display everything ***BUT*** the `Location: https://www.something.com`

I tried to hardcode the `webResponse.Headers.XXX` myself like I have with the web responses, however, no avail.

Comment: *I would like to remove the Location from the Headers section of the C# code.* and *What changes do I need to make to my code to remove everything but the Location?*.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I would like to display everything *but* the `Location: https://www.xxxxxxx.com` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all the headers by using `webResponse.Headers.Keys`.

```
foreach (string key in webResponse.Headers.Keys)
{
    if (key != "Location")
    {
        var value = webResponse.Headers[key];
        headers.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew. Instead of `Console.WriteLine` could I do `headers.Add(..)`?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I thought this was a display issue.  You can add individual headers by doing `headers.Add(key, value);`

Comment: Also, isn't it a good idea to use `.Equals("..")` instead of `!=`. I think I'll change that.

Comment: I've updated my code, in the first part, replace `var` with `string`.  I forgot that `webResponse.Headers` predates generics.  This should fix the compile error.