# How to hide IP from location param in response

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http, asp.net-web-api2

In my API I have method, which create resourece. When everything is ok I return 201 HTTP code (created). There is snippet of my code.

```
var locationUrl = Request.RequestUri + "/" + id;
return Created(locationUrl, response);
```

In header I see location param in this format: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/resource/id
I want to avoid share IP address in header, I prefer to present DNS name.

How can I do this? Some of my collegues think that it is unsecure, I could be true?

Comment: You are actually basing your response on the request URL. 
So your clients already now your IP address if they used it as “RequestUri“. 
I really don’t see a problem.

Comment: @Jurion unless your server is behind load balancer/CDN/proxy - and that IP has nothing to do with what user actually sees.

Comment: Even in this case, you’ll return the same IP address as your public load balancer IP address. If not (I did not work a lot with load balancers behind Azure), your URL for resources (DNS) should be pretty match static, as your load balances/cdn will auto redirect request to right the server on the fly. Can’t you just store it somewhere ot directly query your load balancer/cdn server for public address?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code here, it's read all the headers by using `webResponse.Headers.Keys`and then search for the that contain the "*Location*":

```
foreach (string key in webResponse.Headers.Keys)
{
    if (key != "Location")
    {
        var value = webResponse.Headers[key];
        headers.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Check ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788722/removing-a-particular-header-item-in-http-web-requests)*** answer for more information.